# How to compute magnetic field in python?

Tags: python-3.x

How to compute the magnetic field according to equations in cylindric coordinates (R, theta, z), please? I tried it in code below, but the result is scaler value in x, y, z. Where is the mistake, please?

Code consists of the function for interpolating and the function where the equations are written.

[image]

```
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ndarray
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator as rgi, RegularGridInterpolator

def my_3d_interp(x: ndarray, y: ndarray, z: ndarray, V: ndarray,
                 xi: ndarray, yi: ndarray, zi: ndarray) -> ndarray:
    interpolating_function: RegularGridInterpolator = rgi((x, y, z), V)
    return interpolating_function(np.array([xi, yi, zi]).T)
    return dxdt

def fields(x: object = None) -> Tuple[ndarray, ndarray]:
    if x is None:
        x: ndarray = np.zeros(3)    
    R: ndarray
    theta: ndarray
    z: ndarray
    R, theta, z = np.mgrid[0:1:11j, 0:np.pi * 2:25j, -0.5:0.5:11j]
    Bmat: ndarray = np.zeros([3, R.shape[0], theta.shape[1], z.shape[2]])

    # (R, theta, z)

    # it is enough to define non-zero values

    # R
    Bmat[0, :, :, : ] = np.where((x[0]  >= 0) & (x[0]  <= np.pi), 0.25 / 3 * R ** 2 * np.sin(z), 0)

    # theta
    # Bmat[1, :, :, :] = 0

    # z
    Bmat[2, :, :, :] = np.where(x[2]  < 0, x[0], 0)
    Bmat[2, :, :, :] = np.where((x[2]  >= 0) & (x[2]  <= np.pi), 0.25 * x[0] * np.cos(z) + 0.75 * x[0], 0)
    Bmat[2, :, :, :] = np.where(x[2]  > np.pi, 0.5 * x[0], 0)

    # Linear axis due to the interpolation
    R = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 25)
    z = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 11)

    # Interpolate
    B_R = my_3d_interp(R, theta, z, (Bmat[0, :, :, :]), x[0], x[1], x[2])
    B_theta = my_3d_interp(R, theta, z, (Bmat[1, :, :, :]), x[0], x[1], x[2])
    B_z = my_3d_interp(R, theta, z, (Bmat[2, :, :, :]), x[0], x[1], x[2])

    E_R, E_theta, E_z = 0, 0, 0

    # Results to matrices
    return np.array([E_R, E_theta, E_z]), np.array([B_R, B_theta, B_z])

E, B = fields([0.5, np.pi / 2, 0.5])    
print(B)
```